# MySQL grouping from complex query

Tags: mysql, group-by

I need to create a query that looks like this image with the result:

[image: table screen shot]

You can ignore the names of the user, user_id is fine for now. Each user can have several timesheets for one day. So I need to count the hours and place it in its own column for day of the week. Then have a total at the end. Here is a screen shot of the database:

[image: database screen shot]

Here is what I have so far that gets me the days of the week totals but not grouped in one record with the day of the week as its own column and a total. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
SELECT user_id, WEEKDAY(start_date) AS day, (select time_to_sec(timediff(end_date, start_date )) / 3600) AS hours FROM `timesheet_table` WHERE id > 0 GROUP BY day, user_id
```

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: No idea why someone gave this a vote down. It is a very clear and concise question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need  a totat you can use  a sum and group by

In Group by you can't use the alias but you should use the expression

```
  SELECT 
        user_id
      , WEEKDAY(start_date) AS day
      , sum((select time_to_sec(timediff(end_date, start_date )) / 3600)) AS hours 
  FROM `timesheet_table` 
  WHERE id > 0 
  GROUP BY WEEKDAY(start_date), user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

E.g.:

```
  SELECT user_id
       , DATE(start_date) dt
       , SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(end_date)-TIME_TO_SEC(start_date))) day_total
-- [or , SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(end_date)-TIME_TO_SEC(start_date))/3600 day_total] 
    FROM my_table 
   WHERE start_date BETWEEN '2016-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-10-07 23:59:59' 
   GROUP 
      BY user_id
     , DATE(start_date);
```

The rest of the problem (missing days, display issues, weekly totals, etc.) would normally be handled in application level code.